# <v-icon> vuetify material Icon (mdi) showing problem in vuetify and nuxt app?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt and vuetify. all of the tags working fine. But when I am using `<v-icon>`, the icon is not showing ..

```html
<v-flex xs12 mb-3>
  <v-btn outline fab small color="blue-grey lighten-4">
      <v-icon color="grey darken-4">mdi-facebook</v-icon>
  </v-btn>

  <v-btn outline fab small color="blue-grey lighten-4">
      <v-icon color="grey darken-4">mdi-google-plus</v-icon>
  </v-btn>

  <v-btn outline fab small color="blue-grey lighten-4">
     <v-icon color="grey darken-4">mdi-linkedin</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</v-flex>
```

Comment: have you installed the material design icon and font and config it ?

Comment: Yes I have..     https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/icons

Answer (score 18):

## Here is what worked for me:

Start by adding the following to the `vuetify: {}` object in nuxt.config.js:

```js
defaultAssets: {
  font: true,
  icons: 'md'
},
icons: {
  iconfont: 'md',
}
```

Then refer to your icons **without** the 'mdi-' prefix as follows:

`<v-icon>feedback</v-icon>`

> Please note that I only have 2 hours of Nuxt.js experience so there is likely a better way, but I hope this helps people get started :)

---

> Edit: I figured out that there are two different icon libraries that Vuetify can come with (depending on which instructions you follow for installation). One is [md](https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline) which you use **without** prefixing your icons and the other is [mdi](https://materialdesignicons.com/) which you use **with** the "mdi-" prefix.

Comment: Glad to hear it @Photonic :)

Comment: @AmanuelNega I already did in the edit at the bottom (I also linked to them both)

Comment: This was the best solution I found until now :)

Answer (score 8):

The unofficial google's repository definitely works, can't testify for others. Try the CDN link first

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Alternatively, install locally using yarn or NPM

```
$ yarn add material-design-icons-iconfont -D
```

// OR

```
$ npm install material-design-icons-iconfont -D
```

Then import in your vuetify.js file

```js
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'md',
  },
})
```

Thats all

Comment: for me, use `cdn` not working... but if use `npm`, it is working